# Does uuidv1() generate differently?

Tags: uuid

I am confused about uuidv1(). In the following code it uses `uuidv1()` as a salt and encrypt a password. But I thought that `uuidv1()` generates different strings so that I am not able to use it to encrypting a password.

Does `uuidv1()` generate always the same strings?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uuidv1 = require("uuid/v1");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    hashed_password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    salt: String,
...
});

// virtual field
userSchema
    .virtual("password")
    .set(function(password) {
        // create temporary variable called _password
        this._password = password;
        // generate a timestamp
        this.salt = uuidv1();
        // encryptPassword()
        this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
    })
    .get(function() {
        return this._password;
    });

// methods
userSchema.methods = {
    authenticate: function(plainText) {
        return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashed_password;
    },

    encryptPassword: function(password) {
        if (!password) return "";
        try {
            return crypto
                .createHmac("sha1", this.salt)
                .update(password)
                .digest("hex");
        } catch (err) {
            return "";
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

uuidv1 does generate a unique output everytime which is why you save that as salt in the user model

so uuid creates salt which is like alphabet for crypting strings, uuid has like v1, v2 ... check out their npm doc, i checked it and it was simple, then your userSchema encryptPassword crypts your password using crypto (you imported it in user model) based on that "salt" alphabet and you store the outcome as hashed_password which in future will be used in comparison, based on the saved salt every time